# How can I set the date when some row is created? I'm trying to use only Triggers and Functions at PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, procedure, database-trigger

I have a table called **recipes** and my goal is for each time that I insert a new row, the column **created_at**, of this new row, automatically receives the value **NOW()**.

I manage to do something like this on the column **updated_at** creating this function and trigger, and it's working fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_set_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at = NOW();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp
BEFORE UPDATE ON recipes 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_set_timestamp();
```

But after I changed the code to set the **created_at** nothing happens and the Postgres doesn't point any errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_set_timestamp_created_at()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.created_at = NOW();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp_created_at
AFTER INSERT ON recipes 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_set_timestamp_created_at();
```

Comment: Your insert trigger has to be a **`BEFORE`** trigger as well

Comment: Thank you, it works!! Right now I'm having problems accepting your answer because the "checkmark" is not appearing... I'll try again to mark as correct in a couple of hours